# Java FX automation using UFT

Tags: vbscript, automation, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

Please suggest if there is any way to automate the testing of Javafx application using UFT 12.02 as UFT is unable to identify the objects in JavaFx application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the Java Add-in enabled? Did you open UFT *before* opening the application? Can you give an example of a JavaFX application you are trying to automate and why isn't it identifying the objects? Please provide further info to work with

Comment: Yes I had opened the tool before opening UFT, This application is a Window application built using java FX and UFT just recognizes this as a 'Window' and no hiearchy tree is displayed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=UFT+Java+fx+addin&oq=UFT+Java+fx+addin&aqs=chrome..69i57.13575j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8), you would find out that UFT has no direct support for JavaFX applications.

This link talks about it:
https://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/QTP-not-recognizing-JavaFX-controls/td-p/5793877

A brief summary on the answers:

> QTP does not have any separate add-in specifically for those controls,
>   QTP has only the standard Java add-in that would work if the mentioned
>   controls are Java standard controls and if they belongs to the
>   standard Java Swing classes or Java AWT clases, only standard no any
>   kind of customized nor third party control. Otherwise, the recognition
>   will be basic because QTP will not support the controls.
>
> You can find more information about the technologies that support the
>   Java add-in in the next link at page 4:
>
> **HP QuickTest Professional 11.00 Product Availability Matrix**
>
> http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM1210389
>
> Actually we have an Enhancement Request to evaluate the prosiblitiy to
>   bring support to JavaFX objects:
>
> **Support for JavaFX 2.0.2.**
>
> https://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/FID/DOCUMENTUM_QCCR1J26625
>
> For the moment as a workaround we recomend work with these kind of
>   controls as third-party controls.
>
> **How to work with unsupported or third-party controls**
>
> http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM186906

I don't have further knowledge about it as I've never worked with JavaFX before, but I belive here you will find enough content to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Please check out UFT 14.01, it is supported natively now.

> UFT now supports testing applications built with JavaFX, natively using the Java Add-in.
>
> Prior to 14.01, JavaFX was supported by Microsoft UI Automation for
>   purely JavaFX widgets.

You can find the documentation here: https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/latest/UFT_Help/Content/Landing_Pages/Whats_New_Landing_Page.htm#hp-minitoc-item-2